# Change system locale inside a CentOS/RHEL without using localectl?

Tags: docker, locale, systemd, rhel

I'm trying to build a Docker image based on [`oracle/database:11.2.0.2-xe`](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance) (which is based on Oracle Linux based on RHEL) and want to change the system locale in this image (using some `RUN` command inside a `Dockerfile`).

According to [this guide](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-set-locales-i18n-on-a-linux-unix/) I should use `localectl set-locale <MYLOCALE>` but this command is failing with `Failed to create bus connection: No such file or directory` message. This is a [known Docker issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/7459) for commands that require SystemD to be launched.

I tried to start the SystemD anyway (using `/usr/sbin/init` as first process as well as using `-v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro -v /run` thanks to [this help](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/7459#issuecomment-283888347)) but then the `localectl set-locale` failed with `Could not get properties: Connection timed out` message.

So I'm now trying to avoid the usage of `localectl` to change my system globale locale, how could I do this?

Answer (score 9):

According to [this good guide](https://www.shellhacks.com/linux-define-locale-language-settings/) on setting locale on Linux, I should use

```
localedef -c -i fr_FR -f ISO-8859-15 fr_FR.ISO-8859-15
```

But this command failed with

```
cannot read character map directory `/usr/share/i18n/charmaps': No such file or directory`
```

This [SO reply](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/140517/29674) indicated one could use `yum reinstall glibc-common -y` to fix this and it worked.

So my final working `Dockerfile` is:

```
RUN yum reinstall glibc-common -y && \
  localedef -c -i fr_FR -f ISO-8859-15 fr_FR.ISO-8859-15 && \
  echo "LANG=fr_FR.ISO-8859-15" > /etc/locale.conf

ENV LANG fr_FR.ISO-8859-15
```

Comment: for ol8 (ORACLE Linux) oraclelinux8: `microdnf install glibc-langpack-ru` `localedef -i ru_RU -f UTF-8 ru_RU.UTF-8` `echo "LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8" > /etc/locale.conf` for Russian (русской) locale at `openjdk:11.0.11-oracle` docker container `export LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8` OR `ENV LANG ru_RU.UTF-8`
to `Dockerfile`

Comment: It didn't work for me in ubi8 out of the box. To make it work you have to install `glibc-locale-source` package. Otherwise localedef will complain: `[error] character map file UTF-8 not found: No such file or directory`